# Access variables in the Redirect in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-login

Templates are rendered in login based on groups.How can I access these variables in my template.For example how can I access these variables in redirect like the context in render? Here is my code.
error is:

> name 'username' is not defined

Views.py

```
def login_user(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    all_requests= Retest.objects.all() 
    projector_requests = Eventprojector.objects.all()
    classroom_requests = Eventclassroom.objects.all()
    lab_requests = Eventlab.objects.all()
    mikesystem_requests = Eventmikesystem.objects.all()
    extensioncable_requests = Eventextensioncable.objects.all()
    auditorium_requests = Eventauditorium.objects.all()
    graphicshall_requests = Eventgraphicshall.objects.all()
    u = User.objects.get(username=username)




    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            if user.groups.filter(name='Rep').exists():
                return redirect('/rep')
            elif
                #..........(other groups)

            else:       
                return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})

        else:
            return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
  return render(request, 'retest/login.html')
@login_required
def rep(request):

    u=User.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'retest/home.html', {'u':u})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
url(r'^rep$', views.rep, name='rep'),
```

Comment: what are `these` variables? Post atleast one example

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. What data are you trying to access, and - more importantly - *where*?

Comment: Edited the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a redirect response, you are telling the browser to load a new URL. When the browser requests the new URL, you no longer have access to the old context in the new view.

If you need to pass information to the new URL, you can include it in the URL you redirect to e.g. `/rep/22/` or `/rep/?id=22`, or by saving data in the session.

However, in this case you don't need to do that, because you can simply access the logged in user with `request.user`.

```
@login_required
def rep(request):
    u = request.user
    return render(request, 'retest/home.html', {'u':u})
```

You don't even need to include `u` in the context. Since you are using the `render` shortcut, you should be able to access `{{ user }}` in the template, as long as the auth template context processor is enabled.

```
@login_required
def rep(request):
    return render(request, 'retest/home.html', {})
```